# Let $p$ be a prime. Prove that $x^2\equiv 1\mbox{ mod }p$ if and only if $x\equiv 1\mbox{ mod }p$ or $x\equiv p-1\mbox{ mod }p$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

I am a little confused about how to start a proof like this. Any pointers are appreciated. Thank you.

Let $p$ be a prime. Prove that $x^2\equiv 1\mbox{ mod }p$ if and only if $x\equiv 1\mbox{ mod }p$ or $x\equiv p-1\mbox{ mod }p$. Useful note aside: $p-1\equiv -1\mbox{ mod }p. Why?$

Comment: Any if and only if problem has two parts, the forward and reverse direction. The reverse direction seems easier. Let $x$ be of the form $pk + 1$ and $pk - 1$ and then square and see what you get

Comment: "Any if and only if problem has two parts, the forward and reverse direction. "  Wellllll, yessss.... but if every step of the proof is reversible going in one direction implies the other direction will work and you don't have to do it.  But *EVERY* step *must* go in both directions.

Answer (score 1):

$x^2\equiv1\bmod p$ means $p|x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$, which means $p|x-1$ or $p|x+1$,

which means $x\equiv1\bmod p$ or $x\equiv-1\bmod p$.

$-1\equiv p-1\bmod p$, because the difference of $p-1$ and $-1$ is $p$, which is divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 1):

This will fall into your lap like magic.

The definition of $x^2 \equiv 1 \pmod p$ means that $p|x^2 -1$.  And as $x^2-1 = (x+1)(x-1)$ then $p|(x+1)(x-1)$.

But $p$ is prime and we've got this thing called Euclids lemma so either $p|x+1$ or $p|x-1$.

But the definition of $x \equiv 1 \pmod p$ is $p|x-1$ and the definition of $x \equiv-1\pmod p$ is $p|x-1$.

So either $x\equiv 1\pmod p$ or $x \equiv -1\pmod p$.

Oh... okay... one more thing,not hard.  $x\equiv -1 \pmod p \iff p|x+1 \iff p|x+1 -p\iff p|x-(p-1)\iff x\equiv p-1 \pmod p$.

If you blink, you'll miss it.

Comment: Thank you so much. I don't think we touched on Euclid's theorem in class so I didn't know where to go after writing out the definition of modulo.

Comment: "I don't think we touched on Euclid's theorem in class" Oh, you must have.  It's practically impossible to do any number theory without it.  If $p$ is a prime and $p|ab$ then either $p|a$ or $p|b$.... This isn't true if $p$ isn't prime. Example $p=35$ then the $5*7=35$ so $(6-1)(6+1)=35$ so $6^2-1 =35$ so $35|6^2-1$ so $6^2\equiv 1\pmod{35}$.  But $6\not\equiv \pm 1\pmod {35}$ and $35$ doesn't divide either $5$ nor $7$. Instead $35$ can "split" between $5$ and $7$.  A prime can not split.